# Column Lists or Table Alternative for Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

I'm coming to all of you because I'm stumped!  I need to setup the press page on our website in a different way that I have already.  Currently, I made a table that includes four columns which works, but since we are working with current at the top and old at the bottom, we sometimes end up with three columns (or so) at the top of the table.

[image: Current table version]

So to solve this, I thought I would just create an unordered list and use inline css to make it four columns.
    `<ul>
    <li style="display: block; width: 25%; float: left;"><a href="link"><img src="image"/></a>
    <br>Title<br>Date</li>
    <li style="display: block; width: 25%; float: left;"><a href="link"><img src="image"/></a>
    <br>Title<br>Date</li>
    <li style="display: block; width: 25%; float: left;"><a href="link"><img src="image"/></a>
    <br>Title<br>Date</li>
    </ul>`

Well instead of it working like I thought it would, the following is a screenshot of what happened:

[image: Not working unordered list columns]

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I might get this working?  I'm stuck within the restrictions of wordpress and our css file is a mess, so I'd rather not mess with that and instead use inline (especially if we decide to change it again).

Thanks for any help and suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving each LI a height should solve your problem, also you could add a margin or some padding to each LI to space them out a bit.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This sent me on the right track...I added the margin-bottom property and was able to work out the spacing.  I've decided to make all of the icons uniform, though, which is work now, but will save me individual margin-bottom issues later!

Comment: Making all the icons the same size will certainly take all the hassle out of your problem. Glad you got it sorted :)